# Copy items from NSMutableArray to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I try to copy items from NSMutableArray to another.

I add items in my two first MutableArray (`storiesRSS1` and `storiesRSS2`):

```
[item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
[item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
[item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"]; 
[item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];
[item setObject:currentImage forKey:@"image"];
[item setObject:currentMovie forKey:@"movie"];
[storiesRSS1 addObject:[item copy]];


[item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
[item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
[item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"]; 
[item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];
[item setObject:currentImage forKey:@"image"];
[item setObject:currentMovie forKey:@"movie"];
[storiesRSS2 addObject:[item copy]];
```

For these two arrays it work.

After that I want to mix both in a third array (`stories`).

```
int i=0;
int nbElement=[storiesRSS1 count]+[storiesRSS2 count];
while (i<nbElement) {
    if (i<[tempArrayTed count]) {
        [stories addObject:[storiesRSS1 objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    if (i<[tempArrayYoutube count]) {
        [stories addObject:[storiesRSS2 objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    i++;
}
```

But when I try to show each items, it's always `null`!

Could you help me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`NSMutableArray` has an `addObjectsFromArray`: method that you might find useful.

```
[stories addObjectsFromArray:storiesRSS1];
[stories addObjectsFromArray: storiesRSS2];
```

On a side note, you're leaking memory when you do:

```
[storiesRSS1/2 addObject:[item copy]];
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to alternate each elements storiesRSS1 and storiesRSS2.

First item of stories is first item of storiesRSS1
Second item of stories is first item of storiesRSS2
Third item of stories is second item of storiesRSS1
Fourth item of stories is second item of storiesRSS2
...

Comment: Might be worth taking a look at insertObjects:atIndexes: then. Eg, add all the items from RSS1, then insert the objects from RSS2 at the relevant indexes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `stories` is nil. Any message sent to nil just returns nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
stories=nil;
[stories release];
stories=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
int i=0;
int nbElement=[storiesRSS1 count]+[storiesRSS2 count];
while (i<nbElement) {
    if (i<[tempArrayTed count]) {
        [stories addObject:[storiesRSS1 objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    if (i<[tempArrayYoutube count]) {
        [stories addObject:[storiesRSS2 objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
    i++;
}
```

since it seems you might not be allocating memory to stories Array. Hope that works.If this is not the case then try to print storiesRSS1 &storiesRSS2 Arrays.